# Login Problems with Greenaddress

Tags: wallet-recovery, windows, green-address

I need help desperately!   I am trying to get to BTC that is locked in a greenaddress wallet.  I can log into the view only. When I put in the mneumonic & password, the system runs through decryption to 100 percent and then it bombs out and says login failed.  I've contacted or tried to contact support for help and they say things like that it's not mapped properly or  the fact that I can get in to see it but just not touch the actual account only proves that one exists!  I have the NLock Times zip file.  Can you please help me?  I don't know at all what to do to try to recover these funds. I have a PC running Windows 10 and don't know anything about code, programming languages or any Unix based systems or how to use or run anything like that.  I can pay someone if they can help retrieve these BTC's from the greenaddress wallet to sweep to just about anywhere else on God's green Earth.  Please please can someone help me?  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the steps fail, comment below, I'll try to help.

1) Follow the tutorial here to install [Ubuntu for Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#0)

2) Set your Username and Password

3) Type

```
sudo apt-get update -qq
```

After commands that start with `sudo`, it'll ask for your password. You'll need to type it, but it won't be shown on screen for security. Press enter.

4) Type

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev build-essential python3-virtualenv virtualenv -yqq
```

5) Now, in Windows, visit https://github.com/greenaddress/garecovery and download it via "Clone or Download -> Zip" Move it to your desktop

6) Go back to the Linux terminal. Type `cd` with a space after it. Drag & Drop the unzipped folder. Now, press enter.

7) Type and enter

```
pip uninstall enum34
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install --require-hashes -r tools/requirements.txt
pip install .
```

8) You can now continue the final step, which is located [here](https://github.com/greenaddress/garecovery#2of2-recovery)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will try this & let you know how it goes.  I can't tell you how much I appreciate someone finally taking the time to actually talk to me human to human

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know the result. 

Comment: Hello.  I really want to thank you for trying to help me.  I just don't know what goes wrong.  I completed 7.  But then I go the greenaddress site to finish and again, it just doesn't work.  Please Please Please...  I have all of the emails (confirming the authentification steps).  I have the mnemonics, user name and password.  I have the picture QR but it won't take it.  It says it's not clear enough.  The only thing I don't have is a pin.  I have the nlocktime zip and I can see in the view only that the BTC's are still there. I can pay you to help me. The nlocktime email says to use gentle

Comment: @JENNY could you please give me the exact output of the last step?

Comment: So, I wasn't exactly sure what I was supposed to type in the  Ubuntu, but I tried using the exact phrase garecovery-cli 2of2 --nlocktime-file /path/to/downloaded/nlocktimes.zip -o garecovery.csv.  It said something to the effect of that it couldn't find it in the directory? Then, I thought maybe I was supposed to drag and drop the file where it  said file/path, etc.  like in your instructions (which worked very well up until this part).  After that, it just kept showing my username/command prompt over and over again.

Comment: But I will try again if I have clearer instructions.  Also, I'd be more than willing to give you this information.  If it turns out that this was never mapped properly (because I've heard this being a possibility a couple of times now) what does that mean, how could that happen and what could possibly be done about such a thing?

Comment: I haven't heard of "not mapping correctly", it'd be great if you could show a website mentioning it. I believe the error might be caused by the Windows Subsystem, since we used it instead of creating a full VM. You may need to try all these steps again in a real VM, are you familiar with installing Virtualbox and completing a basic installation of Ubuntu? It shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: It's funny you mention that.  I had Ubantu partitioned so that anytime I booted up, I had to choose which operating system I wanted to use.  I must have done something wrong there, too, though because it had all the apps that worked & I could get online, but my uncle gave me a couple of basic commands to run and none of them did anything. When I say "mapped" I mean the wallet itself being connected to or identified as being connected to a rightful owner.  I know the mnemonic is correct & the password.  It shows decryption & then says, "Login Failed." I can view only the wallet on greenaddress.

Comment: But I would be willing to try to reinstall the Ubuntu again, partitioned on its own.  The thing is, I believe the problem is not on this end, but that back in 2015 when the account was created, somehow, the identification information wasn't assigned properly.  There was only 1 transaction done (the one which was the reason for opening the acct. to begin with in 2015). But again, I can give someone the mnemonic, username, password & money for helping but so far nobody has been able to get into it.  The money still shows it's sitting there in the wallet in the view only.

Comment: That's why trying recovery.

Comment: Basic desperation.  I just don't understand why  I wouldn't be able to give someone at greenaddress the username, password, mnemonic, QR, the original emails with the authentification verification numbers & the nlocktime zip & have someone help to get into the wallet. But nobody @ ga does anything to help, unless you work for/with them.  In that case---  it seems you are a loner-- it-  the only one willing to help at all & thank God for you, I'm not joking.  You are truly an angel.  A Godsend & I imagine a very tired & busy one at that. So thank you & thank you again.  You have got it goin on!

Comment: @JENNY Did the `virtualenv venv` step print any errors? If not, please try the last step again with the `-d` argument: `garecovery-cli 2of2 --nlocktime-file /path/to/downloaded/nlocktimes.zip -o $HOME/Desktop/greenaddr.csv -d` Make sure to change the `--nlocktime-file` path by drag dropping. `-d` will output everything so that we can understand the problem. Please paste the whole input to [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/) if the output is too long, and post the link to it below.

Comment: Will do.  Thank you again for taking your time to do this. :)

Comment: I don't really know how to do that or what you mean.  But if there is somewhere I can attach a document or clip, I've basically done screen shots and literally recorded myself trying to open this wallet.

Comment: I did that gentle tutorial and it showed it worked to 100%.  Would I be better off maybe trying to do that instead?  I just don't actually know how to get that to run, either. I think you guys assume that everyone lives and understands Unix.  Lots of us, however, don't.  It is like a foreign language to us and this really doesn't help matters .  I have a coinbase account and you know what I do when I have a problem?  I call their customer service and someone walks me through on the phone or handles it on their end.

Comment: But whoever you are....  you are the exception to the general statement that greenaddress is more than lacking in their customer service.  Youi've taken a great deal of time to try to help me when I don't know the first thing about anything you tell me.  But, I did follow through and got to the last part.  All I can say (because I don't know how to copy and paste anything-- cntrl  A & C & V don't seem to do the trick) is I saved my work by doing screen shots of all of it and saved it in a word document.

Comment: Also, I do have a clip showing me trying to get into the wallet, itself and the decryption showing up to the 100% and then the "Logon Failed" popping up.  Also, I show that I can get into the view only.  I have the nlocktime zip.  I just don't understand why I can't seem to be able to log in in the first place, why I have to try to do this recovery, why it's n ot working and why someone can't just take what I have and get the wallet open?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9r0m31nufmp5gxa/Ubuntu-Wallet%20Recovery%20Attempt%2001.docx?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxjrpiralvyq7gs/GA%20Login%20Failure.MOV?dl=0

Comment: Please let me know if you would be willing to help me off this public forum so I can provide you with any info you would need in order to help me.  I can attach the nlocktime, mnemonics (&QR Code ), user name, password, etc. but I won't drop those into the dropbox and  publically announce where that information is                                                   for obvious reasons.   Again, I really appreciate the time you've taken to assist me.  I am apparently special needs.  Sorry about that.

Comment: (Note: you can paste with Right click -> paste) Firstly, please unzip `garecovery.zip` in Windows and then use `cd` into the unzipped folder. Then `virtualenv venv` then `source venv/bin/activate` then `pip install --require-hashes -r tools/requirements.txt` (notice the `-` between `require` and `hashes`) lastly `pip install .` (<-- `.` here) Thanks for the screenshots, now I can try to help easily. Let me know after you do these steps @JENNY